# Vmware Fusion Mouse Support

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have noticed a few annoyances with the latest version of VMWare Fusion:

- With a new Logitech Marathon mouse m705, the forward and back buttons do not seem to work as intended (ex: instead of going back in the browser it resizes it)
- The scroll speed of the mouse is way off in some applications.  It's not a seamless experience between OS X and VMWare at all.  For example, on the Windows 7 side I might open the nook application and scrolling is way too fast.

Are these common issues with VMWare Fusion or am I missing something?  I have the latest VMWare Tools installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same issues, I recommend downloading Steermouse and removing the Logitech drivers. Steermouse solved my issues.